# ancestors.shift is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I'm trying to get automated tests back up and running and having the following issue when I run a test.

The objective of the function is if the selector comes from a section of a page object selector will be an array of objects starting from the outermost ancestor (section), and ending with the element Join their selectors in order.

**Error message:**
`Error while running "getElements" command: ancestors.shift is not a function`

**Function:**

```
function getSelector(selector) {
    let ancestors = selector;

    if (typeof ancestors !== "string") {
        selector = "";

        let oElement = ancestors.shift();
        while (oElement) {
            selector += " " + oElement.selector;
            oElement = ancestors.shift();
        }
    }
    return selector;
}
```

**The code which calls the getSelector function below:**

```
selector(selector) {
        return featureHelper.getSelector(selector);
    }

    getElement(result) {
        if (result.status === 0 && Array.isArray(result.value)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
                if (typeof result.value[i] === "object") {
                    result.value[i].ELEMENT =
                        result.value[i][Object.keys(result.value[i])[0]];
                }
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You state that `selector` should be an array. But, clearly it is not, since `shift` is not a function. In order to help you from here, we need to see the code that calls the `getSelector` function.

Comment: @aridlehoover Thanks for your response, I have added the code that calls the getSelector function to description.

Comment: Hey thanks @chinwc! There's still not enough context for me. I wonder if you could reproduce the problem in an executable code block. Or... keep going up the call stack to show me where the variable selector is defined...